# Show alert from shared class in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to make a alert function to be used by all the view controllers:

```
import UIKit
class MyFuncs: NSObject {

    static let shared: MyFuncs = MyFuncs()

    func MsgBox(msg: string)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message:msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

// add an action (button)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

// show the alert
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

However, it works from (view controllers).swift but not from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in AppDelegate.swift.  What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Try the debugger.  Does the function get called?  Does `appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?` evaluate to something non-nil?

Comment: Yes it gets called, and it works if I call it from within a viewcontroller (viewDidLoad) but it doesnt popup if I call it from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.

Comment: When it doesn't work, what's the value of `appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?`?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble figuring out how to call an alert from an arbitrary class (I was using an extension originally, but like you I ran into problems when I needed to call it outside of a view controller), so instead I wrote a function to create a new window to display the alert in:

```
extension UIWindow {
    static func makeWindow () -> UIWindow {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.windowLevel = (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.windowLevel ?? 0) + 1
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return window
    }
}
```

And made an alert subclass with all the logic to call it:

```
class MyAlertController: UIAlertController {
    let alertWindow = UIWindow.makeWindow()

    static func doAlert (_ title: String, alertMessage: String) {
        let alert = MyAlertController(title: title, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then just call `MyAlertController.doAlert` whenever you need to use it.